# Grails: Find class property based on Date

Tags: grails

I have a Grails 2.4.3 application that uses Oracle as the database.

There's a class called User:

```
class User {

    String userName = ""
    String userPassword = ""
    Date userAdded
}
```

In a controller i am using the following code to find all user names.

```
def names = User.where { }.projections { property 'userName' }.list()
```

Now i want to find User Names based on the date in which they were added to database.

For e.g., if a date range is provided as between 12/01/2014 to 12/12/2014, Now i want to get all the User Names added during that period.

Is there a easy way of doing it?

Comment: What have you tried with the above `where` query assuming you have already visited [docs related to WHERE Queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
Date start = // get the start date
Date end = // get the end date

def userNames = User.withCriteria {

  ge('userAdded', start)
  le('userAdded', end)

  projections {
    property("userName")
  }
}
```